# Summarizing fold-changes in a data.frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with values for 100 ids (e.g. genes), measured from 10 `group`s (e.g., cell types), where each of these `group`s come from 10 `family`s (e.g., tissues), 3 samples per each such `id`-`group`-`family` combination, i.e. a  total of 30000 rows:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(paste0("i",1:100),300),
                 group = rep(unlist(lapply(1:10,function(g) rep(paste0("g",g),100))),30),
                 family = unlist(lapply(1:10,function(f) rep(paste0("f",f),3000))),
                 val = rnorm(30000))
```

I want to create a `data.frame` that for each `id` in each `group` in each `family`, calculates the fold-change between its mean `val` and the mean `val`s of all other `id`s from that `group` and `family`.

Here's what I'm doing now but I'm looking for a faster implementation, which can probably be achieved with `dplyr`:

```
ids <- paste0("i",1:100)
groups <- paste0("g",1:10)
families <- paste0("f",1:10)

res.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(ids,function(i){
  do.call(rbind,lapply(families,function(f){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(groups,function(g){
      data.frame(id=i,group=g,family=f,fc=mean(dplyr::filter(df,id == i,group == g,family == f)$val)/mean(dplyr::filter(df,id != i,group == g,family == f)$val))
    }))
  }))
}))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @PoGibas about your question's lack of clarity and just assume that you try to reproduce your final data frame `res.df` in an efficient way. At this point, I believe @PoGibas' answer doesn't give the format you want and some people may find `data.table`'s syntax less accessible compared to `dplyr` (I don't mean to compare them, both packages have their own advantages). Here is one possible `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
# assuming that df and res.df are already loaded as given in the question

by_id_group_family <- df %>%
  # group by id, group and family 
  group_by(id, group, family) %>%
  # calculate some useful features of the grouped data 
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    total_val = sum(val), 
    avg_val = mean(val)  
  )

by_group_family <- df %>% 
  # group by group and family
  group_by(group, family) %>% 
  # calculate some useful features of the grouped data 
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    total_val = sum(val), 
    avg_val = mean(val) 
  )

# store mean vals for each id samples in each group in each family
mean_ids <- by_id_group_family$avg_val

# compute mean vals of all other ids in each group in each family
# note that shorter list will recycle here 
# and we have a minus at the beginning as we are subtracting bigger sum from smaller one
mean_other_ids <- -(by_id_group_family$total_val - by_group_family$total_val) / 297

# computing the ratio of means
ratio <- mean_ids / mean_other_ids

# combining the ratio with the grouped data
result <- by_id_group_family %>%
  # choose only the first three columns
  select(1:3) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # add a new column to store ratio
  mutate(fc = ratio)

# note that result has the same info as your res.df but family column is sorted differently
head(result)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   id    group family      fc
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 i1    g1    f1        9.48
# 2 i1    g1    f10      -4.86
# 3 i1    g1    f2      -50.4 
# 4 i1    g1    f3       17.2 
# 5 i1    g1    f4      131.  
# 6 i1    g1    f5        4.03
```

It is possible to make the code more concise by combining some steps and removing extra computations but I think this way is easier to follow and extra summary stats help me understand the nature of your data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

```
library(data.table)
dfM <- setDT(df)[, mean(val), .(id, group, family)]
cbind(dfM[, outer(V1, V1, "/"), .(group, family)],
      dfM[, expand.grid(id, id), .(group, family)][, .(Var1, Var2)])
```

#### Explanation:

I would solve this task differently (without iteration). First off all we have to clarify your problems:

1. Calculate mean of `val` for each `id`, `group` and `family` combination
2. Divide each mean product by other mean products for each `group` and `family` combination

---

To calculate mean I will use `data.table` (I'm using `data.table` for later calculations per group too), idea is **not** to re-calculate mean multiple times.

```
library(data.table)
dfM <- setDT(df)[, mean(val), .(id, group, family)]
# Result
# head(dfM)
#    id group family          V1
# 1: i1    g1     f1 -0.12587944
# 2: i2    g1     f1 -0.20889324
# 3: i3    g1     f1 -0.02890183
# 4: i4    g1     f1  0.77509410
# 5: i5    g1     f1  0.11435116
# 6: i6    g1     f1 -0.59556654
```

To calculate fold change (ie, divide vector by vector) we can use `outer` function. Here we are asking to divide vector `V1` by vector `V1` within `data.table` `dfM` by each `group` and `family` combination.

```
 foo <- dfM[, outer(V1, V1, "/"), .(group, family)]
 # nrow(foo)
 # 1000000
 #    group family         V1
 # 1:    g1     f1  1.0000000
 # 2:    g1     f1  1.6594708
 # 3:    g1     f1  0.2295993
 # 4:    g1     f1 -6.1574322
 # 5:    g1     f1 -0.9084181
 # 6:    g1     f1  4.7312457
```

`outer` doesn't give us information about `id`'s, for that we use another `base` R function `expand.grid`.

```
bar <- dfM[, expand.grid(id, id), .(group, family)][, .(id1 = Var1, id2 = Var2)]
```

And for final result use `cbind`:

```
head(cbind(foo, bar))

head(cbind(foo, bar))
#    group family         V1 id1 id2
# 1:    g1     f1  1.0000000  i1  i1
# 2:    g1     f1  1.6594708  i2  i1
# 3:    g1     f1  0.2295993  i3  i1
# 4:    g1     f1 -6.1574322  i4  i1
# 5:    g1     f1 -0.9084181  i5  i1
# 6:    g1     f1  4.7312457  i6  i1
```

This solution takes seconds with given OP's data.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(paste0("i",1:100),300),
                 group = rep(unlist(lapply(1:10,function(g) rep(paste0("g",g),100))),30),
                 family = unlist(lapply(1:10,function(f) rep(paste0("f",f),3000))),
                 val = rnorm(30000))
```

Comment: PoGibas, the `cbind(dfM[, outer(V1, V1, "/"), .(group, family)],
      dfM[, expand.grid(id, id), .(group, family)][, .(Var1, Var2)])` code is giving this error for my real data: `negative length vectors are not allowed`. I assume this is because in my real data not all `id`s appear in all `group`s and `family`'s. Can your solution be modified to allow that?